# Laravel pagination pretty URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is there a way to get a pagination pretty URL in Laravel 4?

For example, by default:

```
http://example.com/something/?page=3
```

And what I would like to get:

```
http://example.com/something/page/3
```

Also, the pagination should render this way, and appending to the pagination should appear in this way.

Comment: for Laravel 5.8 - please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58005778/1916821

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a hacky workaround. I am using Laravel v4.1.23. It assumes page number is the last bit of your url. Haven't tested it deeply so I'm interested in any bugs people can find. I'm even more interested in a better solution :-)

Route:

```
Route::get('/articles/page/{page_number?}', function($page_number=1){
    $per_page = 1;
    Articles::resolveConnection()->getPaginator()->setCurrentPage($page_number);
    $articles = Articles::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate($per_page);
    return View::make('pages/articles')->with('articles', $articles);
});
```

View:

```
<?php
    $links = $articles->links();
    $patterns = array();
    $patterns[] = '/'.$articles->getCurrentPage().'\?page=/';
    $replacements = array();
    $replacements[] = '';
    echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $links);
?>
```

Model:

```
<?php
class Articles extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'articles';
}
```

Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateArticlesTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function($table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('articles');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It's possible but you need to code a bit.

First you need to change in `app/config/app.php` pagination service provider - you need to write your own.

Comment:

```
// 'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
```

and add

```
'Providers\PaginationServiceProvider',
```

in providers section.

Now you need to create your PaginationServiceProvider to use custom pagination factory:

`model/Providers/PaginationServiceProvider.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class PaginationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bindShared('paginator', function ($app) {
            $paginator = new PaginationFactory($app['request'], $app['view'],
                $app['translator']);

            $paginator->setViewName($app['config']['view.pagination']);

            $app->refresh('request', $paginator, 'setRequest');

            return $paginator;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return array('paginator');
    }

}
```

Above you create `Providers\PaginationFactory` object, so now we need to create this file:

`model/providers/PaginationFactory.php` file:

```
<?php


namespace Providers;

use Illuminate\Pagination\Factory;


class PaginationFactory extends  Factory {

    /**
     * Get a new paginator instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $items
     * @param  int    $total
     * @param  int|null  $perPage
     * @return \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator
     */
    public function make(array $items, $total, $perPage = null)
    {
        $paginator = new \Utils\Paginator($this, $items, $total, $perPage);

        return $paginator->setupPaginationContext();
    }        
}
```

Here you create only `\Utils\Paginator` object so now let's create it:

`model/Utils/Paginator.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace Utils;



class Paginator extends \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator {


    /**
     * Get a URL for a given page number.
     *
     * @param  int  $page
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl($page)
    {
      $routeParameters = array();

      if ($page > 1) { // if $page == 1 don't add it to url
         $routeParameters[$this->factory->getPageName()] = $page;
      }

      return \URL::route($this->factory->getCurrentUrl(), $routeParameters);
    }
}
```

In this file we finally override default method for creating pagination urls.

Let's assume you have route defined this way:

```
Route::get('/categories/{page?}',
    ['as'   => 'categories',
     'uses' => 'CategoryController@displayList'
    ])->where('page', '[1-9]+[0-9]*');
```

As you see we defined here route name using `as` (it's important because of Paginator implementation above - but you can do it of course in different way).

Now in method `displayList` of `CategoryController` class you can do:

```
public function displayList($categories, $page = 1) // default 1 is needed here 
{
    Paginator::setCurrentPage($page);
    Paginator::setBaseUrl('categories'); // use here route name and not the url
    Paginator::setPageName('page');

    $categories = Category::paginate(15);


    return View::make('admin.category')->with(
        ['categories' => $categories]
    );
}
```

When in your view you add:

```
<?php echo $categories->links(); ?>
```

you will get generated urls this way:

```
http://localhost/categories
http://localhost/categories/2
http://localhost/categories/3
http://localhost/categories/4
http://localhost/categories/5
```

without ? in query string

However in my opinion something like this should be added by default or at least it should be enough to extend one class and not to create 3 classes just to implement one method.

Comment: Thanks for solution, I agree with you, it's really hard to override some default functions in Laravel, it always requires to create new own service provider, it have to be some kind of override generator.

Answer (score 1):

hope this is helpful for someone, I've made a trait to be used in models.
The idea is that this custom method can detect current route and adjust links  to use correct segment position for {page} parameter:

https://gist.github.com/zofe/ced0054e6ac6eff1ea95

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 5.8 use this solution in blade.php where you generate links:

```
    $links = $data->links(); 
    $patterns = '#\?page=#';

    $replacements = '/page/';
    $one = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $links);

    $pattern2 = '#page/([1-9]+[0-9]*)/page/([1-9]+[0-9]*)#';
    $replacements2 = 'page/$2';
    $paginate_links = preg_replace($pattern2, $replacements2, $one);
    echo $paginate_links;
```

Comment: I am using laravel 8 and this should mark as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing this is by extending the Paginator class to do the matching. However, just know that it may conflict with third-party packages and other classes/libraries. The current method is designed to work with nearly all classes/libraries/packages.

**Perhaps you could try the following:**

http://packalyst.com/packages/package/desmart/pagination ('pagination' by 'desmart')

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is using laravel version 5.6+

You can pass additional parameters to set the page number.

According to: https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_paginate

Example:

StoreController.php

```
/**
 * Show sale item based on given page
 *
 * @param int $page
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showPage($page = 1)
{
    $saleItems = SaleItem::paginate(10, array('*'), 'page', $page);

    ...
}
```

Then, in your blade template. You can just `route( ... , array('page' => $page));`

Comment: please explain your answer, because this not clear how to build /some-url/page/2 instead of /some-url?page=2 using your approach.