# How to change page link in Laravel pagination

Tags: laravel, pagination

By default, Laravel pagination generates and parses links to pages in following format: `example.com/search?page=1`.
I want to change it to `example.com/search/1`.

However, I haven't found where Laravel stores such setting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel pagination pretty URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974404/laravel-pagination-pretty-url)

Comment: @lukasgeiter Thank you, haven't found that question. Mine can be closed.