# Laravel 5 pagination links

Tags: php, laravel, url, parameters, pagination

I have a laravel 5 application in which I`m trying to do a pagination for certain results (array of results not collection).
This is my code:

```
$paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator(
 $l_aResponse['body'],
 count($l_aResponse['body']),
 '2',
 Paginator::resolveCurrentPage(),
 ['path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()]
);
return str_replace('/?', '?', $paginator->render());
```

My question is: is there a way to modify the way in which the "page" parameter is setup in the URL for pages? EG: I don't want this format: http://localsite/articles?page=3 but I want http://localsite/articles/3

I`ll appreciate any answer. Thanks!

Comment: this is hardcoded in url() method on the AbstractPaginator class. look here if you are eager to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22442404/3399676

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__construct()` function of the LengthAwarePaginator class has a few parameters:

- $items
- $total
- $perPage
- $currentPage = null
- array $options = []

As you can see the fourth parameter represents the current page.

So you can use a custom desired current page which has been retrieved from the last parameter from the url. An example would be:

```
//  http://localsite/articles/3

$currentPage = ... // Get parameter from url

$paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator(
    $l_aResponse['body'],
    count($l_aResponse['body']),
    '2',
    $currentPage, // Current page as fourth parameter
    ['path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()]
);

return str_replace('/?', '?', $paginator->render());
```

Have not tested this. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your solution! However, this won't allow we to modify the pagination links and the links will still have ?page=1 and so on in the URL. I wanted to strip that out through some sort of parameter or so, and I didn't want to interfere and modify those links via JS or other method.

Comment: I already thought that would happen. Maybe you should play with `'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()`. Or you could create a new paginator class that extends the current `LenfthAwarePaginator` class and overwrite some methods like `render()` .