# laravel 5.2 pagination pretty url

Tags: laravel, url, pagination

I am Using Laravel 5.2

Is There a Way To Get a Pagination Pretty URL in Laravel 5.2?

http://localhost:8000/backend/admin_user?page=10&page=1

And What I Would Like To Get,How generate Link Pretty Url:

http://localhost:8000/backend/admin_user/10/1

Comment: There is example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974404/laravel-pagination-pretty-url

Comment: This example Laravel version 4

Answer (score 1):

So you can try something like that:

`Route::get('test/{page}', function ($page) {
    return User::paginate(2, ['*'], 'page', $page);
});`

Comment: How Generate Links Pagination url=backend/admin_user/10/1

Comment: You cannot put two parameters named page. If you have two pagination you need to put two params with different names:
Route::get('test/{page}/{page1}', function ($page, $page1) {
    $users = User::paginate(2, ['*'], 'page', $page);
    $posts = Post::paginate(2, ['*'], 'page1', $page1);
});

Comment: @Vuer - Where I need to write the following code:
Route::get('test/{page}', function ($page) {
    return User::paginate(2, ['*'], 'page', $page);
});

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with three simple steps.

**Register the route:**

Note the question mark, this makes the `size` and `page` values optional;

```
Route::get('backend/admin_user/{size?}/{page?}', ['uses' => 'BackendController@adminUser']);
```

**Implement this function in your controller:**

Note the default values, `$size = 10, $page = 1`. This makes sure that you don't get an error if you navigate to the url without the pagination.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\AdminUser;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

class BackendController
{
    public function adminUser($size = 10, $page = 1)
    {
        $collection = AdminUser::all();
        $users = new LengthAwarePaginator($collection, $collection->count(), $size);
        $users->resolveCurrentPage($page);

        return view(backend.admin_user);
    }
}
```

**Use in your view like this:**

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        {{ $user->name }}
    @endforeach
</div>

{{ $users->links() }}
```