# Laravel 5.6 Pretty URL Pagination

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to get a pretty url instead of the query string for Laravel Pagination without using a package? I've been looking around and it looks like this won't come out of the box.

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

named route are more specific for this for further read documentation [laravel named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly what kind of pagination you want but you can implement this manually like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39115133/laravel-5-2-pagination-pretty-url).

This package may also be useful ([laravel-paginateroute](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-paginateroute))

You can also customize URL in Laravel ([Customizing The Paginator URI](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results))