# Laravel 5.2 change link pagniation

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I need to change de link to the laravel pagnination.

The pagination of laravel retreun a link like this

```
localhost/blog?page=2
```

I need it to look like this

```
localhost/blog/2
```

i looking this response [Laravel pagination pretty URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974404/laravel-pagination-pretty-url)

but it is for laravel 4.2 And it does not work with the 5.2

i can juste change one option in the

> pafinator.php

or other file

Answer (score 0):

You can [customize pagination view](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view) to build links you want.

> The easiest way to customize the pagination views is by exporting them to your `resources/views/vendor` directory using the `vendor:publish` command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

And then create a new route to handle these links:

```
Route::get('blog/{pageId}', 'BlogController@showPage');
```

Comment: I think this is not available in laravel 5.2 as it is introduced on 5.3

Comment: @ClearBoth you're right, this is a solution for 5.3+. For 5.2 the best way is to create paginator manually, I guess.