# Custom pagination in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello I am working on a laravel project.

I used pagination facades in this project

like `paginate(16);` and in blade file `$data->render()`

which create url like "http://example.com?page=2"

but I want url like "http://example.com/2"

Please let me know how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel pagination pretty URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974404/laravel-pagination-pretty-url)

Comment: You could create the custom pagination using this method specified in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator