# How to change url in pagination?

Tags: laravel-5

In my Laravel 5.7 app I have news page

```
http://mysite/all_news
```

with pagination implementation as:

```
$newsList = PageContent
    ::select(\DB::raw(' page_contents.*, users.username'))
    ->getByPageType( 'N' )
    ->getByPublished( true )
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->join(\DB::raw('users '), \DB::raw('users.id'), '=', \DB::raw('page_contents.creator_id'))
    ->paginate( 4 , null, null, $page)
    ->onEachSide();
```

and route defined as :

```
Route::get('all_news', array(
    'as'      => 'all_news',
    'uses'    => 'PageController@all_news'
));
```

and in view I show pagination :

{{ $newsList->appends([])->links() }}

But rendered links in pagination looks like(and how to render them ?):

```
http://mysite/all_news?=2
```

How to make urls look like

```
http://mysite/all_news/2
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25866939/9193055)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

Specifically:
"Customizing The Paginator URI":

```
$users->withPath('custom/url');
```

> The withPath method allows you to customize the URI used by the
>   paginator when generating links. For example, if you want the
>   paginator to generate links like 
>   http://example.com/custom/url?page=N, you should pass custom/url to
>   the withPath method

Comment: The solution from the linked manual in this answer doesn't address the problem the thread starter mentioned, namely to remove the page number from the query string and make the page number part of the URL `http://mysite/all_news/2`. Anyone ending up here should check @Remul 's link in the  comment above.