# Laravel 5.7 Pagination Pretty URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to create a pagination for post controller, this is my route:

```
Route::get('post/{page?}' , 'PostController@Test');
```

And my action:

```
public function Test($page = 1)
{
    $tests = Test::paginate(15, ['*'], 'page', $page);

    foreach ($tests as $test) {
        echo $test->id;
    }

    echo $tests->render();
}
```

Now I can go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/2` to open page 2, but my pagination url looks like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post?page=2`

Can i fix this?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974404/laravel-pagination-pretty-url) might help.

Comment: BTW, when you go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/2`, it will give you the second post in your db. pagination is different.

Comment: I want `echo $tests->render();` print urls like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/2` `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/3` @GabMic

Comment: I want `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/2` give me second page, i get posts with slug @GabMic

Comment: I've seen it before, I think there is a better way @Ishaan

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to introduce pretty URL for Pagination in Laravel without using external Package.

In one of my project, I was able to build the same using `Laravel Paginateroute` Package.

which you can install by this command :

```
composer require spatie/laravel-paginateroute
```

I have followed the [Documentation](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-paginateroute) provided by the author to implement the same.