# Removing query string from laravel url in pagination

Tags: laravel, pagination

I am using laravel pagination to paginate my products By default It gives me url like this

```
http://example.test/search?page=3
```

But I want some like

```
http://example.test/search/page/3
```

OR If Possible

```
http://example.test/search
```

On every page

This Is How I am doing it now but it is not giving me any result

```
{{  $books->appends(Request::except('page'))->links() }}
```

And I have also tried like this

```
$books = Book::paginate(10);
$books->withPath('/search');
```

But still no result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel pagination pretty URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974404/laravel-pagination-pretty-url)

Comment: as laravel pagination create  query string  ``` ?page=3 ``` like this if u want to use /page/1 then u need to create route for that and handel ur pagination manually

Comment: Can you explain in details ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to generate custom link where you use link() in your blade.php.

```
@php
    $links = $books->links();
    $pattern = $replacement = array();
    $pattern[] = '/'.$books->getCurrentPage().'\?page=/';
    $replacement[] = '';
    $customLinks =  preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $links);
    echo $customLinks;
@endphp
```

Also you can use a package named [laravel-paginateroute](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-paginateroute) from spatie in github.

Comment: Then see this blog [https://stillat.com/blog/2014/07/28/laravel-paginator-pretty-urls](https://stillat.com/blog/2014/07/28/laravel-paginator-pretty-urls) It will help you.