# Laravel pagination custom pagination url

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have a pagination like this:
[www.example.com/region/"region"/category/"category"?page=2](http://www.example.com/region/%22region%22/category/%22category%22?page=2)

I want to change to this:
[www.example.com/region/"region"/category/"category"/page=2](http://www.example.com/region/%22region%22/category/%22category%22/page=2)  
or 
[www.example.com/region/"region"/category/"category"/page/2](http://www.example.com/region/%22region%22/category/%22category%22/page/2)

Any tipp to change question mark to / ?

Comment: you can use the `/` as an url parameters and implpement your custom pagination

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel pagination pretty URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974404/laravel-pagination-pretty-url)